# Backbonejs Marionettejs zombie views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to play with Backbone using Marionete Module.

eg. implementing "Loading spinner" as it has been done in "[contact manager](https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette)" app by David Sulc, the "[backboneye](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/Backbone-Eye/)" plugin for Firefox showing me "Zombie View" after the "Spinner" has been replaced by content. Is it "real" zombie as it has "isDestroyed:true" attribute?

[image: ps of the dom of the zombie]

Also according to the Chrome plugin "[Backbone debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger)" the view has been removed

[image]

Should I worry about them?

here is controller:

```
define(["app", "apps/items/itemsView"], function(app, View){
  app.module("ItemsApp.List", function(List, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    List.Controller = {
      listAllItems: function(){
        require(["common/views", "entities/items"], function(CommonViews){

          var loadingView = new CommonViews.Loading();
          app.main.show(loadingView);

          var fetchingItems = app.request("items:entities");
          var itemsPageLayout = new View.Layout();
          var panelView = new View.Panel(); 

         $.when(fetchingItems).done(function(items){
           var allItemsView = new View.Items({collection:items});   

           itemsPageLayout.on("show", function(){
              itemsPageLayout.panelRegion.show(panelView);
              itemsPageLayout.itemListRegion.show(allItemsView);
           });
         app.main.show(itemsPageLayout);
        });
      });
     }
   }
});
return app.ItemsApp.List.Controller;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have a Zombie view.

If your `main` region uses the default [Marionette `Region` type](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-143) and your views inherit from Marionette View types (`ItemView`, `CollectionView`, `CompositeView`, `Layout`), Marionette ensures that Zombie Views are avoided.

When a view is swapped out of a region (which happens when you call `app.main.show(itemsPageLayout)`), the spinner view element is removed from the DOM and all `listenTo`-style event handlers unbound.

You can see this in the [code for `Region._destroyView`](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-155), which is called on `show`:

```
_destroyView: function() {
  var view = this.currentView;

  if (view.destroy && !view.isDestroyed) {
    view.destroy();
  } else if (view.remove) {
    view.remove();
  }
},
```

Marionette `View` types have a `destroy` method that handles removing the View's DOM element and unbinding event handlers (that were bound with `listenTo` - it is not as simple to unbind events bound with `on`). Views based on vanilla `Backbone.View`, rather than a Marionette type, must unbind their own event handlers. Failure to do this correctly is the main cause of Zombie Views. By using Marionette Views, you are protected.

If you use a custom `Region` type that overrides `Region.show`, you need to ensure that it calls `destroy` on the view that is being swapped out.